# How to get treeview parent and child nodes in dictionary

Tags: windows, forms, linq, c#-4.0

Please help me to get all checked nodes of treeview in dictionary where key is checked parent node and value is list of checked child nodes using linq query using c# .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have only single level of child for each parent, you could do create an Extension method as following.

```
public static class Extensions
{
        internal static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,IEnumerable<string>>> GetSelectedList(this TreeNodeCollection tr)
        {
            var childCollection = new List<string>();
            foreach (var trNode in tr.OfType<TreeNode>())
            {
                if (!trNode.Checked) continue;

                childCollection.Clear();
                childCollection.AddRange(trNode.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>().Where(x => x.Checked).Select(x=>x.Text));

                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>(trNode.Text, childCollection);

            }
        }
    }
```

Now you could use it as following.

```
var selectedData = treeview.Nodes.GetSelectedList().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll check and Mark it as answer.